# JavaScript: How can Get the json.file that it was post to my code?

Tags: javascript, json

Imagine if I want to wait to get JSON file If they post to me. I can get it. if it's not I waite for it. I want to get it and store it and parse it to work on it.
(I need to receive the request )How I can have JSON file I can get it to take what I need then post my HTTP response to the agent that sends me file that file.

my JSON file name is : flow_demo_1

Comment: how are you generating first device_id?

Comment: It is my computer device id.

Comment: okay and you are sure this id is going to match from the file?cause i  find the format both different

Comment: Yes, I am sure.

Comment: Can you please edit your question so it contains *valid* JSON?  That would make your question a lot clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var device_array = { device_id : [["7547092d-e03e-5148-a54f-8276a85d7f70","cpp_node_192-168-56-1:6111"]] };

var from_file_array = [
    { device_id_from_file: "7547092d-e03e-5148-a54f-8276a85d7f70" },
    { device_id_from_file: "93e71ba7-fb56-5592-a5f6-d855203dd7ae" },
    { device_id_from_file: "93e71ba7-fb56-5592-a5f6-d855203dd7ae" },
    { device_id_from_file: "fe21abdf-706f-5c7b-adb8-2507e145e820" },
];

var val = device_array['device_id'][0][0];

for (var i= 0; i < from_file_array.length; i++) {

    if(from_file_array[i].device_id_from_file === val){
        console.log("device ids are matches");
    };
};
```

Comment: This unnecessarily uses jQuery on a question that isn't tagged with jQuery.

Comment: my code has a problem when writing this line :                                                    
 var val = device_array['device_id'][0][0];

Comment: What is your JS error? The code above is working well.

Comment: why is it wrong? I used it but don't work.
          for (var i=0 ; i<device_array.length ; i++) {
  
           for (var j=0 ; i<device_id_file[0].length ; j++) {
            
             if(device_array[i] == device_id_file[j]){
              console.log("device ids are matches");
             }
            } 
          }

Comment: Bro you're missing.device_id_from_file.. if(from_file_array[i].device_id_from_file

Comment: How I can put my variables in var  from_file_array? I extract them with JSON. stringify  I cant put them in (var ) as you wrote!

Answer (score 0):

try this,you just want the which file data is matched right?

```
from_file_array.filter(each=>each.device_id_from_file===device_array.device_id[0][0])
```

it will give the matched device_id_from_file;if not you will get empty array

Comment: Can you write a new one with this new name that I wrote? I wrote it, It doesn't give me the right answer

Comment: add variable names to question where you are getting this data.I Will update it